# jQuery $(function() {}) vs (function () {})($)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that the following is shorthand for `$( document ).ready()`:

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

I also understand what an anonymous JS function is, but does jQuery does anything special when it's called using one. I.e.:

```
(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
})($);
```

Is the latter just a normal anonymous JS function that uses jQuery (ie. it will NOT be considered shorthand for `$(document).ready()` and so will execute immediately)?

I feel this MUST have been asked before, but I can't find it if it has.

Comment: As a side note, I tend to (strongly) prefer to use `jQuery(function($) {//...$ is guaranteed to be jQuery here });` - the "no-conflict-safe" document ready.

Comment: The `(function() { console.log( "ready!" ); })($)` takes the parameter $ but does nothing with it.

Comment: In second case you are passing jquery instance into anonymous function (have no idea why). It will be executed immeidiately.

Comment: The latter in indeed just an anonymous function. I'm not even sure it _does_ anything. Something that you can actually find, however is `( function( $ ) {/* your code*/ })(jQuery)` which makes sure your code has `$` as jQuery (the identifier is sometimes overriden to some different library).

Comment: @cale_b Thanks. I know what an IIFE is, so not looking for an explanation of that. I just wanted to make sure jQuery didn't do something magical and somehow treat it differently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you mentioned, the former is indeed a shorthand for `$(document).ready()`.
As for the latter, this is just an **Immediately Invoked Function Expression**.

```
(function ($) {
    console.log('ready');
})(jQuery);
```

This function is simply an anonymous function which receives a parameter named `$`. The function is *immediately invoked* with some value (in this case `jQuery`) as the parameter.

IIFEs can also be used to *isolate scopes* and to *avoid global variables* in web applications which contain multiple JavaScript files. In this case a parameterless IIFE could be used:

```
(function () {
    // x is only accessible within this IIFE
    var x;
    // do something...
})();
```

For more information regarding **Immediately Invoked Function Expression**, see this question: [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Comment: This is the more accurate answer *specific to jQuery*.  Bonus points for using a "no-conflict-safe" model that will ensure jQuery could be run along with other libraries that use the `$` function name.

Comment: Great answer, but I'm more familiar with the term "Immediately Invoked Function Expression" than "Self Invoking Anonymous Function". Is there a difference? @cale_b?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt You're right, I've added the other term to the answer as well

Answer (score 9):

The first one is, indeed, a shorthand for `$( document ).ready()`, as pointed [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

But the second one is **Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)**, an anonymous function that is declared and immediately called.

In fact, the **correct syntax** (*the argument is missing in your example*) is:

```
(function($) {
    //my $ object is local now
})(jQuery);
```

In this case, you're calling the anonymous function with an argument.

The main advantage of this pattern (IIFE) is: **isolate your code** (you can create as many variables as you want and it'll be restricted to your anonymous function **scope**, unless you return something). This pattern is used a lot to define *"private"* and *"public"* methods. Like this:

```
var myModule = (function() {

    function privateFunction() { console.log("I can't be accessed from outside :("; }

    var privateVar = "me too :(";

    function publicFunction() { console.log("Hey! I'm here!"; }

    /* expose what you want */
    return {
        publicFunction: publicFunction
    }

})();

myModule.publicFunction(); //Hey! I'm here!
myModule.privateFunction(); //undefined;
```

You can also call it **module pattern**.

In your second example, you're calling the recently-created anonymous function with an argument, and your anonymous function receives that argument. This is a way of **dependecy injection**.

This way, you manipulate your global variable inside the function as local. Note that in the first example, we're passing a `jQuery` object and manipulating it inside your function as `$`. It's more difficult to someone override jQuery object, but, some script can re-assign the global dollar symbol, specially if you don't have full control of your app. This way, you're allways passing te `jQuery` object and manipulating it as `$`.

At the end, let me list some other advantages of passing parameters to a IIFE grabbed from [here](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/):

- **it's faster**: JavaScript first lookup into the local scope (before
  climbing up). It may improve performance a bit.
- **helps minification**: minifier can now rename variables inside your
  scope to a one letter word, reducing code size.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the latter just a normal anonymous JS function that uses jQuery (ie. NOT shorthand for $(document).ready() and so will execute immediately)?

Yup, exactly, it's just a normal IIFE which takes the `$` global variable as an argument

```
(function(dollarSignArgument) {
    console.log( "not really ready!" );
})($)
```

it'll be executed immediately

Comment: Thought so. Thanks!